# Select groups dependgin on values in two columns in dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Hello I have a df such as :

```
Groups COL2 COL3
G1 2 8
G1 3 4
G1 0 3
G2 1 3
G2 9 4
G3 3 89
G3 3 5
G4 1 7
G4 2 3
```

and I would like to select only groups if at least a row satisfies the two following conditions: `COL2 < 3` and `COL3 > 5`. Thus here I would select only groups `G1` and `G4`.

```
Groups COL2 COL3
G1 2 8
G1 3 4
G1 0 3
G4 1 7
G4 2 3
```

I tried:

```
df%>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  filter(any(COL2 <3) & any(COL3 >5)) %>%
```

Comment: You have no column named `COL1` in this example, but if you change the `filter` code to the right column names it looks like it gives the desired output.

Comment: I edited, yes but the fact to put any does not mean it will take any value in column ?

Comment: It will consider any value within the group. That's why it excludes groups G2 and G3

Comment: Oh, you mean that you would like to have a row that satisfies both conditions at the same time, and then consider its corresponding group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select only the groups where at least a row satisfies both conditions (instead of having the conditions satisfied singularly at least once within the group), you can use the following.

```
# create vector of groups that satisfy the conditions
ok_groups <- (df %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  filter(COL2 <3 & COL3 >5))$Groups

# filter original dataframe according to ok_groups
df %>% filter(Groups %in% ok_groups)
```

Output

```
> ok_groups
# [1] "G1" "G4"

> df %>% filter(Groups %in% ok_groups)
#   Groups COL2 COL3
# 1     G1    2    8
# 2     G1    3    4
# 3     G1    0    3
# 4     G4    1    7
# 5     G4    2    3
```

#### EDIT

I just insert a shorter solution here for future viewers

```
df %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  filter(any(COL2 < 3 & COL3 > 5))
#   Groups COL2 COL3
# 1     G1    2    8
# 2     G1    3    4
# 3     G1    0    3
# 4     G4    1    7
# 5     G4    2    3
```

Comment: whant if I use : filter(any(COL2 <3 & COL3 >5)) ? in order to have only one step without having to first filter groups names

Comment: That works as you intended, and it's actually shorter to write. Good work!